# Does net core api check jwt expiry date on every request?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, jwt, blazor

I have setup an net core api server.  I send my requests via a blazor client app. I set the expiry of each token to be 2 minutes, but the tokens work for about 7 minutes. Does the api checks the expiration date on every request?

the code I am using are like below. in the startup.cs I have

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                            {
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                            ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAudience"],
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtSecurityKey"]))
                        };
                        });
```

On user login, a token is issued like this

```
var expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2); 

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["JwtIssuer"], // read from appsetttings.json
                _configuration["JwtAudience"], // read from appsettings.json
                claims, // claims added here
                expires: expiry,
                signingCredentials: creds // signature
            );
```

I have two requests: the first on is at 11:52 which is successful while expiry date is 11:49 (you can see it in the next picture)
[image]

and second one is at 11:54 which is unsuccessful

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a feature eliminating desynchronization between servers clocks, you can control it like this, so yes the token validation checks the expiration date on every request:

```
    var expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2); 

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                    _configuration["JwtIssuer"], // read from appsetttings.json
                    _configuration["JwtAudience"], // read from appsettings.json
                    claims, // claims added here
                    expires: expiry,
                    signingCredentials: creds // signature
                );
```